# How to place image on UISlider?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I have to place a slider and want to place an imge on slider. the slider i want is this
[image]

CAn any body help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [UISlider class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You want to set `setThumbImage:forState:` as well as `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:` and `setMaximumTrackImage:forState:`. Use the same images for the minimum and maximum track images, and use `UIControlStateNormal` for the state.

Answer (score 2):

Below code will be in ViewWillAppear...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowslide.png"]
                                stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowslide.png"]
                                 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [slider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.PNG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    slider.minimumValue = 1.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 3.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 0.0;
}
```