# UISlider with image on TrackImage

Tags: objective-c, uislider

I have UISLider with set setMinimumTrackImage and setMaximumTrackImage. Both images have same resolution. If I move slider... images are not showed correctly. They are moving, when I am draging slider control thumb.
I tried to use

```
UIImage * sliderBarImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_b"];
UIImage * sliderBarImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_w"];

sliderBarImage1 = [sliderBarImage1 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
sliderBarImage2 = [sliderBarImage2 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:sliderBarImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:sliderBarImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

With or without stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth its not correct. And when I rotate phone, images on track are scaled incorectly, so informations in image are shifted. 
Similar to image in this post: [How to place image on UISlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089484/how-to-place-image-on-uislider). When I move slider, images are starting to move and colors are not overlapping in min and max track, resulting in ugly effect.

Comment: This is a well known problem. I solved it by putting the other track image on a separate UIImageView and placing it under the UISlider in IB.

Comment: It helped... but setMinimumTrackImage is stil no overlapping correctly.. its stretching its size :(

Answer (score 5):

to avoid stretching image change

```
UIImage * sliderBarImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_b"];
UIImage * sliderBarImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_w"];
```

into

```
UIImage * sliderBarImage1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_b"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
UIImage * sliderBarImage2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_w"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Note that it only works from iOS 5.0 or later on. If you support iOS 4.x, you have to use `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`